# When to use :first-child selector vs first() method in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm confused about what should I be using `:first-child` selector or `first()` method in jQuery?

I want to know the difference. (***I'm not asking difference between `:first` and `:first-child`***)

Comment: _"I'm confused about what should I be using :first-child selector or first() method in jQuery? "_ - that depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: can you tell me the difference?

Comment: There is documentation available for both - are you telling us that you can make nothing of that?

Comment: I'm not asking  about `:first` selector, but `first()` method.

Comment: They're the same thing. The difference between selector and method is irrelevant when the end result is exactly the same.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> After a bit of research, I tried [easy example](https://jsfiddle.net/Dhruvil21_04/2gLzoc8v/) myself and got the
>   difference.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".first-child p:first-child").css("background-color", "yellow");
    $(".first p").first().css("background-color", "yellow");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>:first-child selector</h1>

<div class="first-child" style="border:1px solid black">
  <p>This is a paragraph in a div.</p>
  <p>This is a paragraph in a div.</p>
</div><br>
<div class="first-child" style="border:1px solid black">
  <p>This is another paragraph in a div.</p>
  <p>This is another paragraph in a div.</p>
</div>
<p>This is also a paragraph.</p><br>

<h1>first() method</h1>

<div class="first" style="border:1px solid black">
  <p>This is a paragraph in a div.</p>
  <p>This is a paragraph in a div.</p>
</div><br>
<div class="first" style="border:1px solid black">
  <p>This is another paragraph in a div.</p>
  <p>This is another paragraph in a div.</p>
</div>

<p>This is also a paragraph.</p><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm confused about what should I be using `:first-child` selector or `first()` method in jQuery?

They do very different things. The [`:first-child` pseudo-class](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#first-child-pseudo) makes whatever selector it's a part of only match if an element is *also* a first child of its parent. For instance, `div:first-child` will only match a `div` if that `div` is also the first child in its parent.

In contrast, [`first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/) is applied *after* a set of elements has been selected, and reduces the set to just the first element that matched — which may or may not be the first child in its parent.

They have similar names, but they're completely unrelated.

Note that jQuery also has [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) (rather than `:first-child`), which is a jQuery extension, which is effectively the same as applying `.first()` after the fact. It just does it in the selector engine. And as a jQuery extension, it means jQuery has to handle the selector rather than handing off to the (likely to be much faster) built-in browser selector engine.

Let's look at all three in action:

```js
test('$("div.foo").first()', $("div.foo").first());
test('$("div.foo:first")', $("div.foo:first"));
test('$("div.foo:first-child")', $("div.foo:first-child"));

function test(label, set) {
  console.log(label + ":");
  console.log("  length = " + set.length);
  set.each(function(i) {
    console.log("  " + i + ": '" + $(this).text() + "'");
  });
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;£
}
```

```html
<p></p>
<div class="foo">I'm the first <code>div.foo</code> on the page; I am not the first child of my parent</div>
<div>
  <div class="foo">I'm the first child of my parent</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="foo">I'm also the first child of my parent</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

> Also, what is the best practice to use?

Whichever is appropriate to what you need to do, as they do different things.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between `:first-child` and `first()` is that `:first-child` can return multiple elements with context to its parent.

Check below example

```js
$( "div span:first-child")
  .css( "text-decoration", "underline" )
  .hover(function() {
    $( this ).addClass( "sogreen" );
  }, function() {
    $( this ).removeClass( "sogreen" );
  });
```

```css
  span {
    color: #008;
  }
  span.sogreen {
    color: green;
    font-weight: bolder;
  }
```

```html
 <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div>
  <span>John,</span>
  <span>Karl,</span>
  <span>Brandon</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>Glen,</span>
  <span>Tane,</span>
  <span>Ralph</span>
</div>
```

Here both first child of `div span` are getting selected but now if you use `first()` it will just return first element from all matched elements.

```js
$( "div span").first()
  .css( "text-decoration", "underline" )
  .hover(function() {
    $( this ).addClass( "sogreen" );
  }, function() {
    $( this ).removeClass( "sogreen" );
  });
```

```css
  span {
    color: #008;
  }
  span.sogreen {
    color: green;
    font-weight: bolder;
  }
```

```html
 <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div>
  <span>John,</span>
  <span>Karl,</span>
  <span>Brandon</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>Glen,</span>
  <span>Tane,</span>
  <span>Ralph</span>
</div>
```

In Summary, `first-child` and `nth-child(1)` can return multiple elements with context to parent while `eq(0)`,`:first` and `first()` returns single element.

Hope this helps!